# I can log on a site with python, but not surf any longer

Tags: python, cookies

I am trying to get working a python script that would retrieve and record pages from a site, but whatever the URL I send, I always receive the same partial login page, not complete, and noyhing more.
 Here is what already works :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import cookielib, requests, sys
sess=requests.Session()
user_agent={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
cj=cookielib.CookieJar()
login_data=urllib.urlencode({'login' : 'dva2tlse', 'pass' : 'VeryStrong'})
urlOpener=urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
pars1={ 'login': 'dva2tlse', 'pass': 'VeryStrong' }
url1="http://www.entre-infideles.com/login/loginSubmit"
resp1=urlOpener.open('http://www.entre-infideles.com/login/loginSubmit', login_data)
cook1=resp1.cookies
# 
print '\n---------------- Écriture du fichier ./resp1.html...'.encode('utf8')
Fichier=open('resp1.html', 'w')
Fichier.write(resp1.content) # text.encode('utf8'))
Fichier.close()
print ('\n\tfirefox -P def2 -no-remote resp1.html &\n')
#
url2="http://www.entre-infideles.com/home"
resp2=sess.post(url2, data=pars1)
cook2=resp2.cookies
#
print '\n---------------- Écriture du fichier ./resp2.html...'.encode('utf8')
Fichier=open('resp2.html', 'w')
Fichier.write(resp2.content) # text.encode('utf8'))
Fichier.close()
print ('\n\tfirefox -P def2 -no-remote resp2.html &\n')
# sys.exit(0)
# 
# python ./S.py
```

The problem is that it gives me ONLY a part of the login page, where I can read the number of "credits" that I own, so I know that it is MY account, and that I am successfully logged on, BUT the second request gives the same result.
Thank you to try and tell me how I can go on surfing on this site,
 David

Comment: This might happen if the page is using javascript to load more data. Did you get a full HTML page, or was the ending missing?

Comment: I use python a lot, but for these tasks I love CasperJS (or PhantomJS). Check it out - http://casperjs.org/

Comment: I don't know exactly what it contains; I'll go and see...

Comment: It seems to end normally by </body>
</html>